# when inserting a new file in google drive sdk There is no headRevisionId in the return object

Tags: google-drive-api

when inserting a new file in google drive sdk There is no headRevisionId in the return object

the code example :

```
File file = drive.files().insert(body , mediaContent).execute();

headRevisionId = file.getHeadRevisionId();
```

will have null in the headRevisionId

while the next code will return the value :

```
File file = drive.files().insert(body , mediaContent).execute();    

File file2 = file = gDriveApiClient.files().get(file.getId()).execute();

headRevisionId = file.getHeadRevisionId();
```

Comment: For conflict resolution, you might also want to check http://stackoverflow.com/q/21793871/1097104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been reproduced and reported. Sorry for inconvenience.